# How to copy folders from one directory to another directory with the folders overriting instead of merging?

Tags: windows, powershell, copy, files-folders

I have two folders

```
- source
 folderA
 folderB
 folderC
 folderD

- destination
 folderA
 folderB
 folderE
 folderF
```

I want to, using powershell, copy all direct children of source, to destination and replace folders instead of merging them.
ie: in the example, `folderA` on `destination` would be replaced by `folderA` in `source` (equivalent to deleting `destination/folderA`, and then copying `source/folderA`)

Comment: Why use Powershell, when windows has the excellent Robocopy utility to do what you describe? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

Comment: @DrMoishePippik By using powershell i meant using shell commands, which robocopy would fall into. Can you produce an example of how to achieve this with robocopy as I do not see the override folder flag? I see /lev flag that I might need, but would that not just merge folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated above, Robocopy is excellent for these types of processes.

Here is a simple script that leverages Robocopy's "Mirror" option within Powershell:

```
  # Change the Source Folder Below
$Src = "X:\Source\Folder"
  # Change the Destination Folder Below
$Dest = "Y:\Destination\Folder"
  # The MIR Option
$Opt = "/mir"
Robocopy "$Src" "$Dest" "$Opt"
```

The Robocopy utility is extremely powerful and fast and many more parameters and options are available. They can be found here:
[Microsoft's Robocopy Page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)